# Easy exercise on uniform continuity (a conjecture)

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that $x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $[-N,N]$ and later I will prove $x^n$ is as well.

> I will jump right ahead to $$|x^2 - y^2| = |x-y||x+y| \leq 2N|x-y|$$.
>
> Take $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon}{2N}$.

Now for a more general case

> $$|x^n - y^n| = |x-y||x^{n-1} + yx^{n-2} + \dots +y^{n-1}| < nN^{n-1}|x-y|$$
>
> So take $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon}{nN^{n-1}}$

Now even more generally if the domain is $[-N_1, N_2]$, may I simply take $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon}{n(\max \{|N_1|,|N_2| \})^{n-1}
}$

Comment: You need to bound the unwanted factor $|x^{n-1} + yx^{n-2} + \dots +y^{n-1}|$.

Comment: Aren't they taken care of by choice of my $N$s? For instance the case for $n = 3$ I get $|x^2 + yx + y^2| \leq |N^2 + N^2 + N^2| = 3N^2$?

Comment: This is the idea. Just make sure you got the right bound.

Comment: What is the correct bound?

Comment: Just to be clear, what is $N$?

Comment: You are right...let me make an edit. my $b$ somehow turned into an $N$.

Comment: This looks right to me - it seems like the correct bound.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Your bound is right: see [this](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/2589492.pdf) pag.628 (Example)